# H2 Database Java Servlet Connection Path issue

Tags: java, sql, servlets, h2

Lately I have been looking into having a servlet with a local database. With a bit of research I found [H2 Database Engine](http://www.H2database.com/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS))). This is perfect for what I want but I am having trouble with the local path for my servlet.

Example:

I need to create the H2 Database in my WebContent folder so its apart of the project. However I cannot seem to get the code right to localise it.

Example CODE: - **H2.Jar - Connection String to SQL Database**

```
             String url = "jdbc:h2:"+request.getContextPath()+"/emailDB;IFEXISTS=TRUE";
         Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.
                getConnection(url, "adminuser", "pass");
```

Example CODE (ERROR): - **H2.Jar - Connection String to SQL Database (OUTPUT)**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database "C:/emailservlet/emailDB" not found [90013-174]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:54)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:160)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:139)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:122)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:323)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at emailservlet.msdbcon(emailservlet.java:540)
```

As you can see the issue i am getting is that even though im requesting the  contextpath i am still getting C:/ written before.

If you can help me figure out the error in my code that would be so helpful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: getContextPath() does not return a proper file system path; it returns the webapp URL context path. Probably it is H2 itself that is turning the relative path you are giving it into an absolute path.

Comment: The driver expects file system path where it can create files. It converting the relative path to absolute by using root directory that is your C: drive

Comment: Ah, i am not to sure how to stop H2 from changing the url. since the file should be accessible via the web url contextpath/file. I have used requestcontextpath many times for other applications but i am sure your suggestion is correct about H2. Any ideas how to get round it setting a absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver expects file system path where it can create files. It's converting the relative path to absolute by using root directory that is your C: drive. To get absolute path to WebContent folder you need to use [ServletContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Also it's not a good idea to store H2 file's in WebContent folder you should store them in WEB-INF folder so that its not accessible to users.

Below is how the url should be formed

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/WEB-INF";
String url = "jdbc:h2:"+path+"/emailDB;IFEXISTS=TRUE";
```

This will create H2 files in WEB-INF folder.

Considerations taken from the [Features page](http://h2database.com/html/features.html) on H2Database.com site:

- The database URL for connecting to a local database is jdbc:h2:[file:][]    . **The prefix file: is optional. If no or only a relative path is used, then the current working directory is used as a starting point**.
- The case sensitivity of the path and database name depend on the operating system, however it is recommended to use lowercase letters only.
- The database name must be at least three characters long (a limitation of File.createTempFile).
- The database name must not contain a semicolon.
- To point to the user home directory, use ~/, as in: jdbc:h2:~/test.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Yeah will put it in the WEB-INF for that reason. tried your suggestion with using the real  path and i get C:/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/emailservlet/emailDB which is still looking into the drive. Problem is the application will need to be transported between systems and this won't work:(.

Comment: The path your are getting is because you are running tomcat from inside Eclipse. Regarding the path the H2 database needs absolute path but you are not providing the absolute path but using getRealPath method and it should get the correct absolute path automatically on any system

Comment: ok so bare with me on this!, String url = "jdbc:h2:file:emailDB;IFEXISTS=TRUE"; (File is emailDB) which is local to my servlet.  Error returned is: Database "C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/emailDB" not found [90013-174] - (Looking in my eclipse development suite for the file). Thank you for your persistent help by the way!

Comment: If you read the excerpt from H2 above the prefix file is optional. Now you are just providing file name which is emailDB so it is using current directory which is eclipse folder. Deploy the war file in tomcat and try to run it from outside eclipse you will get different path

Comment: Hi, unfortunetly i don't have a way of running the war on another tomcat server atm :( only locally through eclipse. i tried your suggestion String path / String URl (From Above) but obviously from within eclipse i get the same problem "C:/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/emailservlet/WEB-INF/emailDB" not found [90013-174]. (*Reminder - The not found error isn't the issue - Just the file path*)

Comment: file path is not a issue, as I said before, getRealPath() will always give you correct absolute path on any system you deploy your application on.

Comment: I would personally like to thank you for educating me on this issue, i believe your solution is the correct solution and i have accepted it as the answer. Thank you Abdullah! +1